# Clear the HttpWebRequest UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing Pool

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, httpwebrequest, connection-pooling

is it possible to clear the pool of the current processes' UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing pool, i.e. close all authenticated pooled connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not tried it. But somthing like ( typed directly so watch for errors):

```
MyReq.ServicePoint.CloseConnectionGroup(null)
```

will do the trick.

Note:

- there is no pool. There is a reuse of one open connection.
- It is not something I used or tried. Its from my understanding of the documentation.

Comment: Yes, the trick is to "create" a connection group (e.g. a GUID string) by using it the first time, and after having finished work, close this connection group.